# convert image in swift4 to base64

Tags: swift, image, base64, swift4, encode

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage(named:"imageView")!
let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
base64String = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
print(base64String as Any)
```

My problem is the variable (image) is null, but I'm sure I have selected the correct imageView

Comment: why the php tag though?

Comment: Is there any image file or Asset image set named "imageView"? Also casting to `NSData` is unnecessary, and stating `.lineLength64Characters` probably too.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will only work if the image exists in your asset catalog and the asset catalog is member of your target.

Maybe you just added the file to your project and not to the asset catalog? In this case try

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "jpg") else {
    return
}
guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
    return
}
print(data.base64EncodedString())
```